# After adding an animated background via JQuery, links and buttons doesn't accept inputs

Tags: jquery, html, css

After adding an animated background via JQuery, links and buttons doesn't accept inputs. The buttons and links are literally unclickable.. This code bellow is the jquery part of the animated background of my footer, about section and header.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var header = $('.header');
var about = $('.about');
var footer = $('#footer');

var backgrounds = new Array(
    'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40),rgba(0 ,0 ,0 , 0.40)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg)'
    , 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40),rgba(0 ,0 ,0 , 0.40)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/380769/pexels-photo-380769.jpeg)'
  , 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40),rgba(0 ,0 ,0 , 0.40)),  url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/7103/writing-notes-idea-conference.jpg)'
 , 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40),rgba(0 ,0 ,0 , 0.40)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/541522/pexels-photo-541522.jpeg)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    about.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    footer.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);

}
setInterval(nextBackground, 2500);
about.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
footer.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried with your example, but no such behavior found. Can you confirm if there no other code (css or js) at play?

Comment: `.header {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 padding-top: 0.23cm;
     box-shadow: inset 0px -11px 15px -10px black; 
}`

Comment: That's the css for the header section.

Comment: And no js for now.

Comment: `z-index:1` will cause the header to be non-interactive. Please remove that. This code should be the reason.

Comment: I don't even know why i added z-index xD. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by removing `z-index: -1`. For some reason it disables buttons and links.